# UpdateProgress bars and update Panels

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a grideview that displays rows that will be deleted across servers by the click of a delete button in the footer of the grid. This delete will take a long time so i want an updateprogress bar. I'm not really familiar with it so I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [asp.net video tutorial](http://www.asp.net/learn/ajax-videos/) section.  The one you looking for is: [Use the ASP.NET AJAX UpdateProgress Control](http://www.asp.net/learn/ajax-videos/video-123.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't watch the video but the code available under the tutorial helped out so i accepted your answer. Thanks!